# Don't show the last item in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, dataprovider

I have an enumeration type that I can bind to a `ComboBox` using a data provider, but I want to ignore the `Count` member. I use `Count` to check for bounds of arrays that should have the same number of items as the types present in this enum.

```
enum FingerType
{
    Thumb, Index, Middle, Ring, Pink,
    Count
}
```

I bind this enum to a the `ComboBox` like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:FingerType"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And the `ComboBox` is as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"/>
```

So, my question is how to show all items except the last one?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), don't have that enum value in the first place if it's an invalid value.

Comment: @Charlieface Don't agree. Using count in enums is a common practice.

Comment: You can write an implementation of `IValueConverter` and use that in the binding.

Comment: While I agree with @Charlieface you should consider creating an alternative enum containing the values you want and create a converter to your suggested enum.

Comment: Might be common practice, but so is SQL injection and buffer overflows. If it's wrong, it's wrong.

Comment: @rashmatash please check the answer and let me know. For a long period of time I am using this . Let me know it works for you or not. :)

Comment: @Linker thanks. I ended up using `Enum.GetValues(typeof(FingerType)).Length` to check for bounds and removed `Count` from the enumeration.

Comment: Ok. That's nice however, you can check my way and you can remove any item from enum while loading the data into combo box .:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve that problem in different way using a Dictionary. A sample xaml and c# code of viewmodel is given Below.

**XAML:**

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding FingerTypes, 
                                                           Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFingerType, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                             SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                                             DisplayMemberPath="Value"  
                                             Height="22" Margin="0,3,0,0" />
```

**C# ViewModel**

```
  #region Property FingerTypes: Dictionary<FingerType, string>

        private Dictionary<FingerType, string> _FingerTypes;
        public Dictionary<FingerType, string> FingerTypes
        {
            get
            {
                if (_FingerTypes != null) return _FingerTypes;
                _FingerTypes = new Dictionary<FingerType, string>();

                foreach (FingerType value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FingerType)))
                {
                    if (value != FingerType.Count)
                        _FingerTypes.Add(value, value.ToString());
                }
                return _FingerTypes;
            }
        }
        #endregion

#region Property SelectedFingerType: ContractExpiryTypeEnum

        private FingerType? _SelectedFingerType;
        public FingerType? SelectedFingerType
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedFingerType;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedFingerType= value;               
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**Note:** You can also use list but using dictionary works for me in WPF, Silverlight and UWP platforms. Please check the codes and try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would use own EnumHelper in `ObjectDataProvider` and apply filter in it.

Example for removing last value of enum

```
public class EnumHelper
{
    public Array FilterValues(Type enumType)
    {
        Array allValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        object[] filteredValues = new object[allValues.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < allValues.Length-1; i++)
        {
            filteredValues[i] = allValues.GetValue(i);
        }

        return filteredValues;
    }
}
```

Modified `ObjectDataProvider` in resources:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="FilterValues" ObjectType="{x:Type local:EnumHelper}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="local:FingerType"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```